# How to drop rows from a triangle array

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Suppose the triangular array is given by

```
 T[n_, k_] := T[n, k] = If[k < 0 || n < k, 0, If[n == 0 && k == 0, 1, 
    If[k == 0, T[n - 1, n - 1], (n+1)*T[n - 1, k - 1] + (n-1)*T[n - 1, k - 2]]]];
 Table[T[n, k], {n, 0, 5}, {k, 0, n}]
```

which produces

```
    {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 8, 16, 34}, {34, 35, 61, 104, 218}, 
{218, 204, 346, 506, 868, 1724}}
```

What `Drop`, `Select`, or other, method can be used to only keep the first and last row to establish the set

```
{1}, {1,2}, {2,7}, {7,34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
mylist = {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 8, 16, 34}, {34, 35, 61, 104, 218}, {218, 204, 346, 506, 868, 1724}};

Join[Take[#, 1], Take[#, -1]] & /@ mylist
```

works for this special case.

But you want

```
If[Length[#] > 1, Join[Take[#, 1], Take[#, -1]], #] & /@ mylist
```

in a more general case.

Comment: Carl... yep... thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Another possibiity is to use [`Drop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Drop):

```
list = {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 8, 16, 34}, {34, 35, 61, 104, 218}, {218, 204, 346, 506, 868, 1724}};

Drop[
    list,
    None,
    UpTo[2];;-2
]
```

> {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}

Answer (score 6):

```
lst = {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 8, 16, 34}, {34, 35, 61, 104, 218},
       {218, 204, 346, 506, 868, 1724}};
```

**Extract:**

```
Extract[lst, {{1}, {2 ;;, {1, -1}}}] (* for version 9 *)
```

> {{1}, {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}}

This form of `Extract` does not work in versions 10+. Lengthier version below does work:

```
Extract[lst, Prepend[Thread[{Range[2,Length@lst], {1,-1}}, List, 1], {{1}}]]
```

**Part:**

```
lst[[##]] & @@@ {{1}, {2 ;;, {1, -1}}}
```

**Replace:**

```
Replace[lst, {a_, ___, b_} :> {a, b}, {1}]
```

**Partition:**

The tables produced using the function `T` have a special structure, namely, the last element of entry *i* is the first element of entry *i+1*. So we can take the last elements and partition them to get the desired output:

```
Partition[lst[[;;, -1]], 2, 1, -1, {}] &
```

> {{1}, {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}}

**Fun:**

```
☺ = {#, ## & @@ {##2}[[;;, {1, -1}]]} & @@ # &;
☺ @ lst
```

> > {{1}, {{1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}}

Comment: any thoughts on whether the changes made to `Extract` in V10 that stop the above from working are an oversight or deliberate?

Comment: @Mike, your guess is as good as mine:)

Answer (score 5):

yet another. this takes first and last of each row regardless of value.

```
Prepend[#[[2 ;;, {1, -1}]], #[[1]]] &@mylist
```

> {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}

or

```
MapAt[#[[{1, -1}]] &, mylist, 2 ;;]
```

> same

Answer (score 3):

First and Last work pretty well, though you might need to deal with singletons separately:

```
list = {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 8, 16, 34}, {34, 35, 61, 104, 
    218}, {218, 204, 346, 506, 868, 1724}};

{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ list
{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 list =
  {{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3, 7}, {7, 8, 16, 34}, {34, 35, 61, 104, 218}, {218, 204, 346, 506, 868, 1724}};
```

**1.**

```
MapAt[Nothing, {2 ;;, 2 ;; -2}] @ list
```

{{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}

**2.**

```
ReplaceAt[list, _ :> Nothing, {2 ;;, 2 ;; -2}]
```

{{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}

**3.**

```
MapAt[{1} &, 1] @ Query[All, {First, Last}] @ list
```

{{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}

**4.**

```
drop[{a_, ___, b_ : Nothing}] := {a, b}

drop /@ list
```

{{1}, {1, 2}, {2, 7}, {7, 34}, {34, 218}, {218, 1724}}